# django return 2 same results when search through model?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In my django app, I have a search functionality for users to search through my model. I'm using django's `SearchVector` and `SearchQuery` because I'm using Postgresql as database. Everything works fine except it returns 2 exact same results.

shell

```py
>>> results = MyModel.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'content', 'tag__name'),
              ).filter(search=SearchQuery("some words"))
>>> results
<QuerySet [<MyModel: MyModel object (7)>, <MyModel: MyModel object (7)>]>
```

it's been almost a day now that
i'm trying to fix this problem. It worked fine in development but this problem occurs in production.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who face the same problem! it's because of the many-to-many relationship.

I have to use `.distinct()` to fix this problem and also it looks like `.annotate()` is not gonna work with `.distinct()`.

Solution

```py
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> results = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains="some words") | Q(tag__name__icontains="some words")).distinct()
>>> results
<QuerySet [<MyModel: MyModel object (7)>]>
```

see the docs for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/